# How do i find the inverse laplace?

Tags: laplace-transform

$$
F(s) = \frac{2s-1}{s^2(s+1)^3}
$$

If I try to use partial fractions, I end up with 8 constants to solve for!
Is there some shortcut I'm not seeing? Am I supposed to simplify it first? Am I even doing the partial decomposition right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have five.

$$\displaystyle F(s) = \frac{2s-1}{s^2(s+1)^3} = \frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s^2} + \frac{C}{s+1} + \frac{D}{(s+1)^2} + \frac{E}{(s+1)^3}$$

This will produce:

- $A = 5$
- $B = -1$
- $C = -5$
- $D = -4$
- $E = -3$

The inverse Laplace transform, using this [*table*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) is:

$$-\dfrac{1}{2} e^{-t} (3~ t^2+2~ t~ e^t+ 8~t-10~ e^t+10)$$

Comment: I thought that a quadratic denominator meant that you need a "ax + b" expression.

Comment: Sometimes it does, but not always.

Comment: Is there a quick method to solve for the constants? I know about the "cover up" method, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: I grind it out since I know that always works and I do not have to remember tricks, but you might want to look here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx. SOmeone also posted a very nice write-up on partial fractions on MSE, but I cannot find it at the moment. Regards

Comment: Great follow-up to a great answer! +1

Comment: How was/is your Saturday? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you know some complex analysis, the ILT is the sum of the residues of $F(s) e^{s t}$ at the poles of $F$.  There is a double pole at $s=0$ and a triple pole at $s=-1$, so that

$$f(t) = \left [ \frac{d}{ds} \frac{(2 s-1) e^{s t}}{(s+1)^3}  \right ]_{s=0} + \left [ \frac12 \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \frac{(2 s-1) e^{s t}}{s^2}  \right ]_{s=-1}$$

I leave the details to the reader; the result is

$$-\frac{1}{2} e^{-t} \left(3 t^2+8 t+10\right)-t+5$$

Comment: From what I'm getting, what you did was let the denominator equal zero, then solved for s. Will you elaborate on what poles are and what it has to do with differentiating?

Comment: @Tad: what I did was compute residues of a function at its poles.  Much of complex analysis is centered around the fact that you can determine behavior from poles.  Th residue at a pole $a$ is the coefficient of $1/(s-a)$ in a Laurent expansion of $F$ about $s=a$.  I know that this may seem like gibberish if you are not familiar with complex analysis, but I put this in here for completeness.

Comment: @Amzoti: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{{\rm F}\pars{s} = {2s - 1 \over s^{2}\pars{s + 1}^{3}}.\quad
{\cal F}\pars{t}
=
\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}{\rm F}\pars{s}\expo{st}\,
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\quad\mbox{where}\quad \Re\gamma > 0}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal F}\pars{t}
> &=
> \int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}\,{2s - 1 \over s^{2}
> \pars{s + 1}^{3}}\,\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \lim_{s \to 0}\partiald{}{s}\bracks{{\pars{2s - 1}\expo{st} \over \pars{s + 1}^{3}}}
> +
> {1 \over 2}\,\lim_{s \to\ -1}\partiald[2]{}{s}
> \bracks{{\pars{2s - 1}\expo{st} \over s^{2}}}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\lim_{s \to 0}\partiald{}{s}\bracks{{\pars{2s - 1}\expo{st} \over \pars{s + 1}^{3}}}
=
\lim_{s \to 0}\bracks{%
{2\expo{st} + \pars{2s - 1}\expo{st}t \over \pars{s + 1}^{3}}
-
3\,{\pars{2s - 1}\expo{st} \over \pars{s + 1}^{4}}}
\\[3mm]&= \pars{2 - t} + 3 = 5 - t\tag{2}
\\[3mm]&
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{s \to\ -1}\partiald[2]{}{s}
\bracks{{\pars{2s - 1}\expo{st} \over s^{2}}}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{s \to 0}\partiald[2]{}{s}
\braces{{\bracks{2\pars{s - 1} - 1}\expo{\pars{s - 1}t} \over \pars{s - 1}^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}\,\expo{-t}\lim_{s \to 0}\partiald[2]{}{s}
\bracks{{\pars{2s - 3}\expo{st} \over \pars{s - 1}^{2}}}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\expo{-t}\underbrace{\pars{-3t^{2} - 8t - 10}}_{\mbox{From WA}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
By replacing $\pars{2}$ and $\pars{3}$ in $\pars{1}$, we get:
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}\,{2s - 1 \over s^{2}
\pars{s + 1}^{3}}\,\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
=
-\,{3 \over 2}\expo{-t}\pars{t^{2} + {8 \over 3}\,t + {10 \over 3}} - t + 5}\,,
\quad \Re\gamma > 0
$$